ActionController: Which params are set by Rails?
In a JSON API Controller, I use a before_action to check if any key of params is not allowed for that action and respond with a 400 error in case any of the given keys are not allowed.
However, simply iterating over params also yields action, controller and format.
Hardcoding these as "always allowed" seems clumsy and I don't know the list to be complete.
Is there a way to iterate only user-provided GET and POST params?
Is that pollution of params some kind of legacy garbage? We have action_name, controller_name and request.format for the above three.
def check_params
  # determine allowed params based on action
  allowed_params = case action_name
  when ...
  ...
  end
  allowed_params.push(:action, :controller, :format)
  params.each_key do |key|
    return render(json: "key #{key} is not allowed", status: :bad_request) unless key.in?(allowed_params)
  end
end


Nope, the thing is, I don't want to silently drop unpermitted params, I want to respond with 400. I sometimes have optional params, so I also cannot strictly require all allowed params.

As an aside I would argue that 422 is a more suitable response code

Hm, ActionController::ParameterMissing produces a 400 (which is raised if params.require(...) misses), and ActionController::UnpermittedParameters is not even in ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.rescue_respones, which seems rather strange. I think you could argue for 400 and 422. Typically, I respond with 422 if a model fails to save. With 400, it means (for the Rails team also) that the params are malformed.

There are different entities you can use
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/097d0f1088e8e62e81741c5a17c24edcfda99334/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L249-L250
ActionController::Parameters.always_permitted_parameters
# => ["controller", "action"] # default value for strong params, can be changed

Rails.configuration.action_controller.always_permitted_parameters
# => nil # default value to override always permitted params, can be changed in configs

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/097d0f1088e8e62e81741c5a17c24edcfda99334/actionpack/lib/action_controller/log_subscriber.rb#L7
ActionController::LogSubscriber::INTERNAL_PARAMS
# => ["controller", "action", "format", "_method", "only_path"]


Thanks for the insight! Also, I know it is possible to globally either :log or :raise after calling permit if any unpermitted params are detected. The internal method that checks for unpermitted params is also hardcoded to allow :action and :controller, so I guess I am out of luck... Would be nice to :log or :raise only in one place, not globally...
